Azure Static web app - ANGULAR not updating its environment
I have a pipeline in azure dev ops and its working successfully by deploying the application a static web app resource. The only problem is the command is never updating the environment variables in the angular project.
- script: |
      npm install -g @angular/cli
      npm install 
      npm run build-dev
    displayName: 'npm install and build'

this is a step in my pipeline
 "build-dev": "ng build --configuration='dev'",

this is in my package.json
    "dev": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
        }
      ],
      "optimization": true,
      "outputHashing": "all",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "namedChunks": false,
      "extractLicenses": true,
      "vendorChunk": false,
      "buildOptimizer": true,
      "budgets": [
        {
          "type": "initial",
          "maximumWarning": "2mb",
          "maximumError": "5mb"
        },
        {
          "type": "anyComponentStyle",
          "maximumWarning": "6kb",
          "maximumError": "10kb"
        }
      ]
    }
  },

This is in my angular.json. When I run it locally and I use http-server on the dist folder I can see the environment variables are updating. I cannot see why on the pipeline is not updating or where its skipping this step.

your build-dev script in the pipeline, is forcing dev configuration, perhaps add another build-prod script, which then uses, prod configuration, or does not specify the config to use?

so with the static app there is a deploying build step what also needs to call the build command so I added it.
  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    inputs:
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ""
      app_location: "/"
      api_location: ""
      app_build_command: 'npm run build-staging'
      output_location: "dist"

